# Magic key in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

**What is the purpose of the following command?**

```
sudo echo t > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

I run it, but I can see no difference in the magic key and its output at dmesg.
Trigger suggests me that the databases of sysrq are involved in the process.

Comment: I would argue that's a pretty obscure question for a beginner ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

according to this site - [red hat manual -> proc-sysrq-trigger](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/en-US/Reference_Guide/s2-proc-sysrq-trigger.html) - you can use this to remotly (for example in an ssh session) execute the magic system request keys.

it makes sense because otherwise, if you have to perform such an task and you're not in reach for the server or the server has no keyboard attached, you can't trigger system request keys.

your example does not work because of different problems.

- according to this site you have to set "/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq" to something other than 0. you have to search the manuals for the right value. then you are able to echo something into "/proc/sysrq-trigger".
- you have to be root for this. "sudo echo SOMETHING > /SOMEWHERE" does not work because of the output redirection ">".

you have to do this like the examples on this [site](http://blogs.oracle.com/joshis/entry/sudo_echo_does_not_work) - a full example would be:

```
su -
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo "t" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

or

```
echo 1 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo "t" | sudo tee -a /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

After i wrote all this i catched probably another issue of your test :). if you execute for example the "t" sysrq key over an remote session or for example an xterm you can't see the output because sysrq output goes to the "real" console. issue dmesg to see the output!

Comment: @Masi: ups, forget about the last paragraph. while it is true it maybe doesn't apply to you because you wrote that you checked dmesg. --fin

Comment: this also works, and may be cleaner than your examples:  `sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq ; echo "t" > /proc/sysrq-trigger'`